# Issues upgrading to HDInsight 3.2 (Hive 0.14.0, Tez 0.5.2)

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I've changed from HDInsight 3.1 to HDInsight 3.2 (Tez 0.5.2, Hive 0.14.0) and started getting a following error while executing hive query. When I excluded columns that contained data for MAP or ARRAY - everything was fine.

> Unexpected exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryMap cannot be cast
>   to java.util.Map  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.processOp(MapJoinOperator.java:311)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
>
> Vertex killed as other vertex failed. failedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1424340440772_0043_1_02 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:null

Answer (score 0):

What has solved this problem for me is setting "hive.mapjoin.optimized.hashtable" to false.

Comment: Victor, I'm following up with our team on this.

Comment: Victor, do you have a repro that you could share?

Comment: This issue doesn't happen to me anymore. Thank you.